# hibernate transaction commit extremely slow when the session cache huge objects

Tags: java, hibernate

Two table A(25k rows) and B(2.2m rows), use hibernate session load all those data(each row represent one object) then do update only one row in A and one row in B in a transaction, I found hibernate behavior is strange: the commit consume about 1.5 seconds to return. However the sql database's log shows the sql update command only consume several milliseconds. hibernate consume most of the time before flush the sql command to database.

So I use jprofiler to find out what it doing:

[image: the cpu recording data]

There are no clues about how the time was consumed. Due to database execute update command very fast, so it must not be blocked by database. If it was doing computation, it should be record by jprofiler(cpu time consuming).

What hibernate doing here? Why the commit so slow?

Comment: I have a question like Why are you loading entire rows for updating one row ?

Comment: Those object always in memory and their modify action is frequent. So I want session cache them to avoid the selection before update

Comment: @jean - Did you find solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have loaded over 2 million objects that are sitting in Hibernate's first level cache you should not be surprised that things are a bit slow. The time is most likely spent going through all those objects looking for changes. If you know that you don't need an object you can evict it from the cache. That will reduce memory consumption and speed up the eventual commit. Just take care not to evict objects that are actually needed or you will create nasty bugs!

Comment: Agree with @ewramner, I think you should use Lazy loading or JIT.

Comment: You are right. I debug into hibernate find it was doing dirty check in loop of all 2 million objects. The jprofiler failed to capture this. But why hibernate do all of objects dirty check it cached even I only pass one object into saveOrUpdate?

Comment: That is the way it is built. For batch jobs (and processing 2 million objects is a batch job in my book) you generally need to process objects in chunks and evict as you go for good performance. Even better would be if you could filter so that you don't read all of them at all, of course.